# opentsdb install process error with code 127

Tags: java, opentsdb

In Order to install openTSDB ,i have already install java(java8) and hbase ,and both of them are worked successfully. But i follow the steps of  OpenTSDB doc, in

./build.sh it came error like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPV3B.png)

so how can i slove this problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Python. If you see the error message carefully it says 'python: command not found'.

Comment: THis is not the reason.Python is already installed.The reason on this is some of java env needed to be install(through apt-get)

Comment: Java already seems to be installed. And the message clearly says python - command not found. Anyways, if you have resolved it, great.